# Max() not filtering out MIN()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

when I use run the query below, it returns duplicate StockNo's because some of them have duplicate WorkInProgress codes (FiWipStatus Code).
Is there a way to exclude the record based on the the MIN() on rowlastupdated?
as always, appreciate any help!

```
SELECT     dbo.InventoryVehicle.StockNo, dbo.VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode, 
MAX(dbo.VehicleSales.RowLastUpdated) AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.VehicleSales RIGHT OUTER JOIN
dbo.InventoryVehicle ON dbo.VehicleSales.StockNo = dbo.InventoryVehicle.StockNo
GROUP BY dbo.InventoryVehicle.StockNo, dbo.VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode, 
dbo.VehicleSales.RowLastUpdated
```

Comment: Can you show us the database schema and some sample data for the relevant tables please? It will help us provide you a solution.

Comment: You `GROUP BY` `dbo.VehicleSales.RowLastUpdated`. Don't do that because (I'm thinking) you want to aggregate by that to get the `MAX` of it.

Comment: you may `ORDER BY` the column you want the `min` and then `SELECT TOP 1...`.

Comment: unfortunately I'm at work and can't get to any sites that would host a file for schematics/ sample data.

Comment: That's a good tip, Bob - it did get rid of a few entries. Hoping to fully resolve the issue with Fdavidov's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it correctly, you need to get the records based on their last update date and time (which is RowLastUpdated). if so, you can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    iv.StockNo
,   vs.FiWipStatusCode
,   vs.RowLastUpdated 
FROM (
SELECT     
    iv.StockNo
,   vs.FiWipStatusCode
,   vs.RowLastUpdated 
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY iv.StockNo ORDER BY vs.RowLastUpdated DESC) AS RN
FROM         
    VehicleSales vs
LEFT JOIN  InventoryVehicle iv ON vs.StockNo = iv.StockNo   
) D 
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

where ROW_NUMBER() will number the rows based on StockNo and order them based on RowLastUpdated in DESC. So, the first row of each distinct StockNo will be the MAX() datetime in your aggregation query. if you want to get the MIN() just change the order to ASC

Comment: I want to upvote just for introducing table aliases.